# Margin and padding collapsing

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using Google Chrome(93.0.4577.82) and I'm having an issue with a div's margin and padding. In summary:

1. Padding + margin - Off-centre
2. Just padding - Off-centre
3. Just margin - Off-centre
4. Neither - Centred

The div is supposed to be perfectly centred on the page. Here's a screenshot with both padding + margin:

[image: Padding + Margin]

And here's one with no margin and padding:

[image: No margin or padding]

The issue is clearly when there's margin + padding.
Here are the div's styles:

```css
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border: 3px solid #85aeed;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 1em;
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition: 0.7s;
    color: #333;
```

According to Chrome's DevTools, there aren't any overriding styles.

View website:
https://github-user-search-development.dillonb07.repl.co/ *Search for a user then you can view the card that's off-centre*

If anyone knows what's going on, please leave an answer or comment below!

Comment: Just letting you know... the website has a server error when I search so I could not view the div.  To try to fix your problem... You can try to add `justify-content: center;`. That may fix the problem. Justifying the content to center should align the items to the middle of the screen horizontally. Align the items to center aligns the items vertically.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't getting the error. I assume my browser was cached! I'll try to fix that. I do currently have `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` applied to the parent div and it doesn't help. However, I found the problem with the `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.user` div is placed inside an `<a>` tag.

One observable behavior is the fact that the div's margin affects where it starts, but doesn't make the parent grow.

There are, of course, many ways to fix it, but here are some suggestions:

- Remove `width: 100%` from `.user` div
- Replace margin of `.user` div with padding of the parent `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can use another div nested to your parent `div`...
and assign the following codes to your parent `div`

```
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center
```

after that use another styles for nested `div`.(write `padding` for this div )